# Make the table_calendar not reset to the current month view when a day in another month is selected

Tags: flutter, dart, table-calendar

I'm using table_calendar from Flutter and when I select a day in another month, the calendar resets it's view to the current month again. I don't want this to happen.

Example:
Today is 28 of March.
I go to the May month and select a day there.
Now, the calendar view goes back to March automatically.

But I still need to mark, on the calendar, which day is today.

Here's my calendar now:

```
TableCalendar(
        calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
        firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
        focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
        selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
          return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
        },
        onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedDay = selectedDay;
            _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            context.read<Counter>().modify(_focusedDay);
          });
        },
        onFormatChanged: (format) {
          setState(() {
            _calendarFormat = format;
          });
        },
        onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
          _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        },
      )
```

Comment: I see `focusedDay: DateTime.now()`, maybe you can replace it by `focusedDay: _ focusedDay` and initiate `focusedDay = : DateTime.now()` ?

Comment: Perfect, I'll make an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see

```dart
focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
```

so I believe each build will reset the focused day of the `TableCalendar` to the current date.

you can use `_focusedDay` instead:

```dart
focusedDay: _focusedDay,
```

and initialise `_focusedDay` with `DateTime.now()`:

```dart
_focusedDay = DateTime.now()
```